# How to modify existing app on AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I added an app in ad-mob manually and then after uploading the app on play store I linked it on ad mob. After some time my app was suspended. So after some modification I again uploaded the app on play-store with different package name and different app name. But this app has the same ad units which were in the last suspended app, and that app is on in my ad mob account. So what should I do now. Is there anything to worry?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the AdMob Key. I guess it is somewhere stored in your App. Create a new one in AdMob and replace the key in your App with the new one.